# Bing map in jQuery dialog not displaying correctly in IE8/9 only

Tags: jquery, dictionary, dialog, bing-maps

I have a jQuery dialog that pops up to display a bing map (birds eye view) on a real estate website I am building.  For some reason, the birds eye view map works great in Firefox and Chrome and Safari, but not on either IE8 or IE9.

For an example, you can view this page:

http://www.nhfinehomes.com/Property/Detail/4126470

The birds eye view is the button right at the top.  Been trying to figure this out for days now.  When the dialog opens, the map is a small square section of the dialog, not the full dialog.

I have tried making the map a fixed width inside the dialog (just to see if that would work) but still no luck.

I think I need to fire some type of refresh when the dialog opens, but I can't seem to determine what that should be.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

the problem definitely is a sizing issue.  I inspected the Bing maps html inside the jQuery UI dialog, and it appears fine in Chrome.  However, in IE, the parent `<div>` which hosts the map tiles has suspiciously small dimensions, which does not seem correct.  It appears that when the jQuery UI JavaScript executes and modifies the DOM element that hosts your map, something must have gone wrong in IE to cause the bing maps control to loose its marbles regarding how large it needs to be. I did notice that you left the jQuery UI dialog re-sizable, and when I tried to resize the dialog, the map seems to correct itself and display correctly.

So as a workaround, try nudging the size of your dialog in the dialog open event to simulate a resize.  This might have the same effect as a user initiated resize and cause the map to correct itself.  As for a more elegant fix, it is hard for me to say since I don't have the source code in front of me.  But I would start with trying to set the map's width and height using JavaScript after you set up your dialog, rather than counting on the default behavior and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I tried resizing the jQuery dialog just before opening and also just after opening.  Unfortunately neither worked.  Also, I am not seeing it work correctly when manually resizing the window.

Comment: @darensanborn Hmm that is strange.  I used IE 9 and a manual re-size seemed to fix it.